# what is SSH, how to learn it's syntax and

Tags: ssh, syntax

i want to know what SSH really is ? does it work with all servers ? (linux or win based)
what's the reference to learn it's syntax.
and is there a way to experience it on local machine ?

Comment: What research have you done, aside from asking here?

Comment: i just lookedup wikipedia. but is just has some definitions for it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH

Comment: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596008956.do

Comment: If you have a Linux system, I recommend `man ssh`.

Comment: no, im on windows. but i can virtualize linux in VirtualBox. is this "man ssh" a linux shell command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `man ssh`
- `man sshd`
- `man ssh_config`
- `man sshd_config`
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4251.txt

should tell you everything you need to know.